# How do I pass specific .on selector into function

Tags: jquery, function, selector

I have two versions of the same code. This first version works great but not for newly loaded content.

```
    // Do some fancy ajax loading and URL rewriting when link is clicked

    var linkButton = $(".jsHistory a");

    linkButton.on("click", function() {
        // If link is already selected do nothing
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
            return false;
        // Else load new content and update URL
        } else {
            linky = $(this).attr("href");
            history.pushState(null, null, linky);
            showActiveLink();
            loadContent(linky);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In this second version I need everything to relate to the specific linkButton clicked and I think it will work. I'm struggling to pass the selector through though.

```
    // Do some fancy ajax loading and URL rewriting when link is clicked

    var linkButton = $(".jsHistory a");

    $(document).on({
        click: function() {
            If link is already selected do nothing
            if($(this).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
                return false;
            // Else load new content and update URL
            } else {
                linky = $(this).attr("href");
                history.pushState(null, null, linky);
                showActiveLink();
                loadContent(linky);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, linkButton);
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this and if I am close as I think to getting this right? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `on()` only accepts a string for delegated event handlers, and not a jQuery object, so you will have to do this:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {
        if( !$(this).parent().hasClass("selected") ) {
            var linky = $(this).attr("href");
            history.pushState(null, null, linky);
            showActiveLink();
            loadContent(linky);
        }
        return false;
    }
}, '.jsHistory a');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HBWyk/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help guys. This answer worked a treat for my problem. I think I understand it now. I'll do a little experimenting so that it sinks in for future. You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. You need to call it on the document for newly created elements as in the second one but you should also pass in the selector to the on function. This way events from only that selector will be received and the "this" element will be the link...

```
$(document).on('click', '.jsHistory a', function(){
    var linkButton = $(this);
    //...
});
```

Comment: The OP is passing the selector at the end, as would be correct when using a map.

Comment: On your jsfiddle try clicking anywhere on the page. You need to pass the selector rather than the queried element:
http://jsfiddle.net/HBWyk/2/

Comment: You're right, you can't pass jQuery objects to `on()` like that, only strings. Did'nt even notice that before.